# Atomicity of Model.create in Mongoose when passing an array of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, odm, nosql

So I understand that MongoDB (and by proxy Mongoose) does not support transactions, but that operations involving a single document are [always atomic](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/). In looking over the Mongoose docs, I ran into Model.create which allows one to pass an array of documents and store them in a single action, like so:

```
var array = [{ type: 'jelly bean' }, { type: 'snickers' }];
Candy.create(array, function (err, jellybean, snickers) {
 // ...
}
```

Is this action atomic? Does Mongo save all the documents at once, or does the Mongoose ODM loop through the array, saving one document at a time? Sources (or source code) would be greatly appreciated. (Also, I'm new, so please, don't shoot!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB Wire Protocol accepts either single document or multiple documents [with OP_INSERT](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/#op-insert).  However, on the server they are still inserted one at a time.

In other words, if the server were to crash part-way through the insert, some documents would be inserted and others would not be.  Within each document you are guaranteed consistent view of it - either it's all inserted or it's not.   But for multiple documents no such guarantee exists.